# Dynamically generate Angular method name prior to making call

Tags: angular

If name = `features` or `navbar` or `heading` (and could be an assortment of other things from a fixed list), how would I dynamically generate the method call in BuilderComponentDataService:

```
  getComponentIcon(name: string): SafeHtml {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(typeof BuilderComponentsDataService[`get${UtilService.toTitleCase(name, true)}ComponentIcon`]);
  }
```

so that it returns either of the following:

```
@Injectable()
export class BuilderComponentsDataService {
  static getFeaturesComponentIcon(): string {
    const primaryColour = 'red';
    const secondaryColour = 'red';
    return `<svg height="160" width="120"><polygon points="100,10 40,198 190,78 10,78 160,198" style="fill:${primaryColour};stroke:${secondaryColour};stroke-width:5;fill-rule:nonzero;"/></svg>`;
  }
  static getNavbarComponentIcon(): string {
    const primaryColour = 'blue';
    const secondaryColour = 'blue';
    return `<svg height="160" width="120"><polygon points="100,10 40,198 190,78 10,78 160,198" style="fill:${primaryColour};stroke:${secondaryColour};stroke-width:5;fill-rule:nonzero;"/></svg>`;
  }
}
```

I've tried the above and the input is just `function`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `typeof` and add `()` to execute the function before returning:

```
  getComponentIcon(name: string): SafeHtml {
      return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(BuilderComponentsDataService[
             `get${UtilService.toTitleCase(name, true)}ComponentIcon`]());
  }
```